# Putting a code fragment in a table without blank lines

Tags: html, css, layout

For a preformatted code fragment that has multiple lines, some of which are indented, the HTML element is `<pre>`. However, when I use this within a table, the browser inserts a blank line before and after the fragment, even when I don't put the tags on separate lines. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Does this not work: <table><tbody><tr><td><pre style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">Test Test2 Test3</pre></td></tr></tbody></table>

Comment: To avoid lots of poor answers, could you post your code to jsfiddle so we can see your exact problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You need to remove the default padding and margin that the browser applies automatically to the element `pre`.

Do this `<pre style="padding:0; margin:0;"></pre>`

If this doesn't remove all the blank space, add `display: inline;` to the style attribute. By default it use `display: block;`